# Program interacting with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, stack-trace

I am currently working on a log system that is used when debugging some other systems that logs user actions, errors etc, it saves the stack trace in case of error.
I would like to be able to use the stack trace to jump to a specific line in the code or at least the right file in eclipse if eclipse is open like you can do when a stack trace is printed in console, is there any way this is possible other than printing the stack trace back out to the eclipse console, preferably directly from my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Eclipse console view, there is an option to create [Java Stack Trace Console](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/console/ref-stacktrace_console.htm) where you can paste your stack trace and then navigate to the code.

Alternatively, if you want to implement your own plugin within Eclipse, you can listen on some local port and navigate to the code, when user clicks on a stack trace in a web browser or an external application.